# Need google_play_service library for AdMob integration

Tags: qt, google-play-services, lib

I integrate my Qt5/Android app to AdMob with some open source library. In this library's README author tells following:

> Copy *google-play-services_lib/*  folders from *android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/* directory to your AndroidManifest.xml location

But I do not have *libproject* in my *android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/* installation. Here in other threads I found recommendation unzip needed library from one of files located at */extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms*. Now I am weird - which one library I have to unzip and use from this folder. In this folder there are 41 library folders with 21 version subfolder in each one. Anybody help me with this. May be I need just download an old *android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/* from somewhere? Where can I take this? I build app for min API 16, target API 23 but I'm going change to latest target API at summer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from this [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/39649/solved-how-to-add-google-play-services-lib-to-qt-for-android/2) should solve your problem:

> 1. Follow this guide https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/
> 2. Add reference to library project. Add project.properties file with:
>
> `@android.library.reference.1=../../../android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib@`
>
> path must be relative not absolute
>
> 3. Prepare google-play-services_lib
> 4. Go to google-play-services_lib folder in sdk and run
>
> Android update lib-project --path . ant clean ant release
>
> Run project in Qt Creator

Comment: Looks like you did not read the question... I have no folder ..../android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib even after "android update". Other say this is because Google turned to Play Services library v30 with another libraries path and structure. Finally I found v29 with needed structure. I have copied and will use it in application but I am not sure if it will be supported by AdMob at future.